# Protect website with password (no username)

Tags: web, password-protection

Are there any ready-made solutions for protecting website (or a single page) only with password (i.e. no username field)? I've been searching around but haven't found anything.

The password protection doesn't have to be particularly strong.

Answer (score 0):

I would use md5 to cipher the password, ask for the password with JavaScript, cipher the result and look if the two values are equivalent:

```
if("<MD5_PASSWORD>" == md5(window.prompt("Password", ""))){
    // right
}else{
    // wrong
}
```

the code for a md5-function in JavaScript you can get [here](http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/javascript/md5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can have the password be sent via the url like `?p=password-goes-here` at the end of the url.

Than at the webpage do:

```
if($_GET['p'] != 'mach-password-goes-here'){
die("Wrong password.");
}else{
//the page content goes here
}
```

for extra security you can hash the password in sha1 and sult

```
if(sha1($_GET['p'].'sdfjkhdsfiosio213ij2') != 'sha1-with-sult-ass-goes-here'){
die("Wrong password.");
}else{
//the page content goes here
}
```